# tfidf from word counts

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a categorical variable with large cardinality (+1000). Each of these values can occur repeatedly in each train/test instance.

Although this is not really text data it seems to have similar properties and I would like to treat this as a text classification problem.

My starting point is a dataframe listing the number of occurrences of each "word" in each "document", e.g.

```
{'Word1': {0: '1',
1: '3',
2: '0',
3: '0',
4: '0'},
'Word2': {0: '0',
1: '2',
2: '0',
3: '0',
4: '0'}
```

I would like to apply tfidf transformation to these "word" counts. How can I do that?

sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer seems to expect a sequence of strings or a file as an input which it preprocesses and tokenizes. None of this is necessary in this case as I already have the "word" counts.

So how to get the tfidf transformation of these counts?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I was trying to recreate TF-IDF from word counts
Try below code, worked for me.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ["The dog ate a sandwich and I ate a sandwich",
          "The wizard transfigured a sandwich"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidfs = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)


from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

columns = [k for (v, k) in sorted((v, k)
           for k, v in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items())]
tfidfs = pd.DataFrame(tfidfs.todense(),
                      columns=columns)
#     ate   dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard 
#0   0.75  0.38      0.54          0.00    0.00
#1   0.00  0.00      0.45          0.63    0.63

df = (1 / pd.DataFrame([vectorizer.idf_], columns=columns))
#     ate   dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard
#0   0.71  0.71       1.0          0.71    0.71
corp = [txt.lower().split() for txt in corpus]
corp = [[w for w in d if w in vectorizer.vocabulary_] for d in corp]
tfs = pd.DataFrame([Counter(d) for d in corp]).fillna(0).astype(int)
#    ate  dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard
#0    2    1         2             0       0
#1    0    0         1             1       1

# The first document's TFIDF vector:
tfidf0 = tfs.iloc[0] * (1. / df)
tfidf0 = tfidf0 / pd.np.linalg.norm(tfidf0)
#        ate       dog  sandwich  transfigured  wizard
#0  0.754584  0.377292  0.536893           0.0     0.0

tfidf1 = tfs.iloc[1] * (1. / df)
tfidf1 = tfidf1 / pd.np.linalg.norm(tfidf1)
#    ate  dog  sandwich  transfigured    wizard
#0   0.0  0.0  0.449436      0.631667  0.631667
```